# PHP variable in query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have tried "everything" to get it working, but I just doesn't :-(

```
$maxcount = 3;
$conn->query("INSERT INTO getal (getal, aantalmaal) SELECT getal, aantalmaal FROM v_topgetallen limit '.$maxcount.'");
```

Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, use a prepared statement; all quote, concatenation and sql injection problems  solved at once.

Comment: You're syntax of the `INSERT INTO` seems wrong, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Hi KIKO, when use 3 instead of $maxcount, everything works fine.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: OK, I'll take it back. :-)

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. Parameterize and itll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$maxcount = 3;

$conn->query("INSERT 
              INTO getal (getal, aantalmaal) 
              SELECT getal, aantalmaal 
              FROM v_topgetallen 
              LIMIT $maxcount");
```

but please use prepared statements.

Comment: Yes! That works!! I'll try to find out if I can use prepared statements. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @franky555 You can find information on [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanx, I'll read about it.